# Reading xml from tar.gz file

Tags: xml, r, tar

I am working with some data file export from MAC system, I guess. I received a file name 20110205.tar then I tried to look at content inside which gave me just raw file ?BIN. My friend helped me to extract it to have a bunch of xml file with the name is in time format: "2011-03-15T23_57_59Z.xml", "2011-03-15T23_58_00Z.xml". I tried with XML package with some commands like xmlTree, xmlTreeParse, asXMLNode then I completely stuck.
When I opened the xml file by notepad I have something like: (my friend used Python to to this but I have no idea about Python)
I also tried with some packages like epidata but it seems many packages are not available for more.
The extracted files I do winrar it and upload to mediafire:
http://www.mediafire.com/?ot8vt0wdw5c3oc1

`<asdiOutput xmlns="http://tfm.faa.gov/tfms/TFMS_XIS" xmlns:nxce="http://tfm.faa.gov/tfms/NasXCoreElements" xmlns:mmd="http://tfm.faa.gov/tfms/MessageMetaData" xmlns:nxcm="http://tfm.faa.gov/tfms/NasXCommonMessages" xmlns:idr="http://tfm.faa.gov/tfms/TFMS_IDRS" xmlns:xis="http://tfm.faa.gov/tfms/TFMS_XIS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tfm.faa.gov/tfms/TFMS_XIS http://localhost:58489/tfms/schema/TFMS_XIS.xsd" timestamp="2011-03-15T23:57:59Z">
  <asdiMessage sourceFacility="CCZM" sourceTimeStamp="2011-03-15T23:57:27Z" trigger="TZ">
    <trackInformation>
      <nxcm:aircraftId>UAL966</nxcm:aircraftId>
      <nxcm:speed>470</nxcm:speed>
      <nxcm:reportedAltitude>
        <nxce:assignedAltitude>
          <nxce:simpleAltitude>350</nxce:simpleAltitude>
        </nxce:assignedAltitude>
      </nxcm:reportedAltitude>
      <nxcm:position>
        <nxce:latitude>
          <nxce:latitudeDMS degrees="45" minutes="40" direction="NORTH"/>
        </nxce:latitude>
        <nxce:longitude>
          <nxce:longitudeDMS degrees="056" minutes="58" direction="WEST"/>
        </nxce:longitude>
      </nxcm:position>
   </trackInformation>
  </asdiMessage>
  <asdiMessage sourceFacility="CCZM" sourceTimeStamp="2011-03-15T23:57:27Z" trigger="TZ">
    <trackInformation>
      <nxcm:aircraftId>UAL936</nxcm:aircraftId>
      <nxcm:speed>470</nxcm:speed>
      <nxcm:reportedAltitude>
        <nxce:assignedAltitude>
          <nxce:simpleAltitude>350</nxce:simpleAltitude>
        </nxce:assignedAltitude>
     </nxcm:reportedAltitude>
      <nxcm:position>
        <nxce:latitude>
          <nxce:latitudeDMS degrees="44" minutes="43" direction="NORTH"/>
        </nxce:latitude>
        <nxce:longitude>
          <nxce:longitudeDMS degrees="062" minutes="42" direction="WEST"/>
        </nxce:longitude>
      </nxcm:position>
    </trackInformation>
  </asdiMessage>`

Please, anyone help me. I want to do anything in R.
1. extract the tar file and decode the raw files become xml file
2. read the data in multiple xml extracted
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What sort of information are you trying to extract? What have you tried? Perhaps you could make a small snippet of one of the files and post it somewhere so that people can have a go at it. Can you adjust the title of your question to reflect of what actually being asked? Clearly you already managed to extract the xml files.

Comment: To extract the contents of a tar file, check `?untar`.
To read XML files, 
the `XML` package (e.g., the `xmlParse` function) can 
create a (complicated) object
that reproduces the (complicated) structure of the XML file.
If you know what you are looking for, you can use `xpathSApply`
to extract the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your operating system, the R `untar` command might help; see `?untar`. As an example of using XML, we can load the document

```
library(XML)
xml = xmlParse("2011-03-15T23_57_59Z.xml")
```

then query it using the [xpath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) language (see especially [section 2.5](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev)), e.g., for aircraft id and longitude

```
> xpathSApply(xml, "//nxcm:aircraftId", xmlValue)
[1] "UAL966" "UAL936"
> xpathSApply(xml, "//nxce:longitudeDMS/@degrees")
degrees degrees 
  "056"   "062"
```

There are also convenience functions such as `xmlToDataFrame`, which might be fun to explore.